# How to set the size of the model in A-frame?

Tags: javascript, aframe

There are 3 different models that appear on the a frame page, but all have the same size. How to register that different model had different size?

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent('model-obj'
  Forest.attrebute( scale 10 20 10)
```

```html
<a-obj-model id="obj_model" position="-55 0 -40" rotation="0 90 0" scale="5 10 5" src="#{{ object.terrain}}"
                     mtl="#{{ object.terrain }}-mtl"></a-obj-model>
  <a-obj-model class="obj_model" id="city-scape" position="-5 0 -40" rotation="0 90 0" scale="5 10 5" src="#{{ object.terrain}}"
                 mtl="#{{ object.terrain }}-mtl"></a-obj-model>
  <a-obj-model class="obj_model" id="city-scape-right" position="50 0 -40" rotation="0 90 0"
                 src="#{{ object.terrain}}" mtl="#{{ object.terrain }}-mtl"></a-obj-model>
```

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent('model-obj'
  Forest.attrebute( scale 10 20 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking the [docs on how to modify a component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/javascript-events-dom-apis.html#updating-a-component-with-setattribute). The provided syntax looks incorrect it should look something like this:

```
  entityEl.setAttribute('scale', {x: 10, y: 20, z: 10});
```